# to click link button it will change the label description using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am new to `ASP.NET` and `C#` and have one doubt.

I have one link button in master page.
When I click that button it will change the label description in the content page.
Can anyone help, it's very useful for me?

Thank you

Comment: have you looked for any asp.net basic tutorial before posting the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `Link Button click event` of master page you can find control of your content page using below mentioned code.

```
protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)(this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("lbl"));

    lbl.Text = "Test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this follow these steps:

- Add an event in the master page class using below code:

  `public event EventHandler MasteridButton_Click;`
- Write this code on button click:

```cs
public void idButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (MasteridButton_Click != null)
  {
    MasteridButton_Click(sender, e);
  }
}
```

- Add this page directive in the page which you want to get this event

```html
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/[YourMasterPageName].Master" %>
```

- Add this code to your page class

```cs
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Master.MasteridButton_Click +=new EventHandler(Master_MasteridButton_Click);
}

protected void Master_MasteridButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lblMyLable.Text = "My Text";
}
```

Comment: Learn to format your answers, see how I edited to know how. In addition your answer is not really relevant, as the label in inside content page and need to be accessed from different page.

Answer (score 0):

You find what your looking for here http://www.snippetbank.net/detail/snippetdetail/9-aspcsharp/8-miscellaneous/556-Update-Content-Label-Text-From-Master-Page.html